# How to make Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") get a value even when the mouse is stopped?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm controlling a game object using my mouse horizontally. The object moves left or right depending on the mouse position but as soon as the mouse stops moving the object stops too. What I want is if I drag the mouse to the right side of the screen and stop moving the mouse, then I want the object to move to the right as long as the mouse is in the right half of the screen and vice versa. Currently Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"); returns a 0 value when stopped. Here's the code:

`float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");`

I've already tried using this fix but I don't get the desired result as im using mousebuttondown to move my player in the forward direction.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && (horizontalInput == 0f))
{
    if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2)
    {
        horizontalInput = -1f;  
    }
    else if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2)
    {
        horizontalInput = 1f;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I can achieve this? Thank you so much for your time!

I fixed it by tweaking the above if conditions to this!

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2 && (horizontalInput < 0f))
    {
        horizontalInput = -1f;
    }
    if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2 && (horizontalInput > 0f))
    {
        horizontalInput = 1f;
    }             
}
```

Comment: Input.mousePosition?

Comment: You mean smg like if(Input.mousePosition.x < (Screen.width / 2)) { Left(); } else { Rigth(); }  ?

Comment: I fixed it by changing the if conditions to check if the horizontal input is greater or less than 0 for left and right movement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check horizontalInput while is not 0 and store the last position each time (just override it each times).
When it's 0 check the last stored position and if it's on the right side continue to move the object until the horizontalInput is 0 or you reach the screen edge.
Of course in the Update you don't even need to loop with a while, you just need to check if horizontalInput is 0 or is not 0.

something like this:

```
float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
float lastPos = 0f;
if(horizontalInput  != 0){
  //move object with the mouse the code you currently use
  lastPos = Input.mousePosition.x;
}else if(horizontalInput == 0 && !EndOfScreen(currentObjectPos.x) && RighLeftScreen(lastPos)){
  Move();
}
```

of course this is just pseudocode. You will need to write a function to know if EndOfScreen right of left, you will need to know if you are on the right or left side of the screen (RighLeftScreen method) and finally you need to move your object Left or Right to the end of the screen.

This is just the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I did something similar and fixed it by changing the if conditions to check if the horizontal input is greater or less than 0 for left and right movement!